Compiling basic Android app without Gradle - d8 errors
I wish to port a small utility I prototyped on Windows as a simple app. I use a 10-year old computer, so from what I gather tools like Gradle and Android Studio would run too slow for me to be able to meaningfully iterate fast. I also know nothing about Android app structure, so seeing the different stages of compilation by compiling from command line is instructive anyway.
I'll list the stages I've been through and then my current error, as I've no idea if my setup or some earlier stage might be causing the issue. I am getting errors trying to compile an example app.
I am following this tutorial : https://hereket.com/posts/android_from_command_line/
(I installed build/platform tools and an image for v28.0.3 and have JDK 22).
The differences I've had are :
1- aapt wouldn't run if the gen folder wasn't explicitely created beforehand
2- d8 refused a *.class parameter, so I've generated the file list manually (Some other user had that issue here : d8: strange exception when using it from command line)
I worked around the issue mentioned here : Error while running dx or d8 tool for Android in the same fashion.
d8 currently gives me the following error :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.android.tools.r8.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:160)
        at com.android.tools.r8.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:143)
        at com.android.tools.r8.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:418)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarClassFileReader.read(JarClassFileReader.java:66)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader$ClassReader.lambda$readClassSources$1(ApplicationReader.java:231)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedInterruptibleCallable.compute(ForkJoinTask.java:1689)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$InterruptibleTask.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1641)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:507)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1491)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2073)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:2035)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:187)

Input command is this :
d8 --debug --output __build\apk\my_classes.jar --no-desugaring  __build\obj\
com\user\android_build_test\MainActivity.class \obj\com\user\android_
build_test\R$attr.class __build\obj\com\user\android_build_test\R$id.class __build\obj\com\user\android_build_test\R$layout.class __build\obj\com\user\
android_build_test\R$style.class __build\obj\com\user\android_build_test\R.cl
ass

The only difference being I give it an absolute path.
If I instead remove all files except one with path removed, I obtain :
Error in R.class:
  Error with input file: R.class
Compilation failed
(etc. - same call stack)

Any idea what causes this ? If so, any idea how I could have worked it out without what seems to be a considerable amount of implicit knowledge ?

I found the issue. It's a silly one, but then again the error d8 spat is not obvious to a Java noob. I'll comment for posterity as I might not be the last person using an older system and toolchain.
I compiled using a version of Java too recent. Older versions of Android (including the one I'm targeting) use Java 8, newer ones Java 11+, if I understood correctly. It may be a bit more subtle than that, but in any case forcing javac to use Java 8 solved the issue.
Using dx (the older build system, not yet removed in the toolchain I worked with) instead of d8 gave me the hint, its error (for me, who hasn't used Java in 10+ years or so) was easier to interpret, or find online.
